# Accessing QWidget child slots/signals from a QWidgetList (QList<QWidget*>)

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlist

I am making a gui app designer. Every time the user create a new widget, it is stored in a QWidgetList. It can be a QPushButton, a QLineEdit, whatever.

For example, let's say I have a QPushButton (index 0) and a QLineEdit (index 1).

Is it possible to access the signal clicked of WidgetList[0], or use the slot setText of WidgetList[1] ?

Or do I really have to make a QList for each type, like QList<QPushButton> and QList<QLineEdit> ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just need to enumerate a widget's signals and slots or you need to know which signal is connected to which slot?

Comment: I need to be able to connect a specific signal to a specific slot, and also retrieve the sender's pointer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the new connect syntax, you have to cast the widgets to correct types. E.g.:

```
QPushButton b{“clear”};
QLineEdit e;
QWidgetList widgets{&b, &e};
QObject::connect(qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(widgets[0]), &QPushButton::clicked,
                 qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(widgets[1]), &QLineEdit::clear);
```

In a designer use case, you’ll probably be referring to signals and slots using their text signatures or `QMetaMethod` handles, and then there’s no need for any casting at all, since those `connect` methods upcast the objects to `QObject` anyway.